# Making Eye-tracking class work as a service in android app

Tags: java, android, opencv, service, eye-tracking

So I am developing a eye-tracking app in android based on OpenCV for educational purposes, to learn the OpenCV tools and Android.

The Eye-tracking works great as a activity but I am now trying to make it work as **a service** but it does not work.

I have put a alert signal in the program so when it does not find the eyes, it gives a alarm. I use this alarm as a testing tool to know if the eye-tracking works in the background, as a service or not.

The eye-tracking code can be found here: https://github.com/eranws/viewFinder/blob/master/src/org/opencv/samples/facedetect/FdActivity.java

**Question**: How can I make this Eye-tracking activity to work as a service? I have tried the usual way, changing activity to a service, according to developer.android.com. But it does not work. Is there another way to make it a service? Perhaps there exits multiple way to do so.

Comment: What is the question more specifically ?

Comment: Hi Morten! The question is: Is there way to make a activity to a service using openCV and how to do so.